# Deploy project to gh-pages from a git clone

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a project that I need to deploy into github pages and add the link to my README. I cannot figure out how to do that from a cloned repository. I created the gh-pages branch using Terminal and then I switched into it and tried pushing it to master but my git hub is still only showing the master branch.

I also tried creating a new repository but I cannot seem to push it on there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [August 2016 and GitHub "simpler GitHub Pages publishing"](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing), you don't have to use the `gh-pages` branch if you don't want to:

As long as your repo is named `<username>.github.io` (replacing `<username.github.io>` with your actual GitHub username), you could simply add a `docs` folder and put your files there, still pushing to master.

But if you are using gh-pages, you can create an orphan branch and put your project files in it:

```
cd /path/to/my/username.github.io
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .
rm '.gitignore'
echo "#Title of Readme" > README.md
git add README.md
git commit -a -m "Initial Commit"
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Then add your project files, commit and push.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the link you provided for github pages and was able to re-submit my project :)